# Numbers of the form $n^k-1$

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, integers

I know that numbers of the form $2^k-1$ are called **Mersenne numbers**. But are there other special numbers which are one less than a power of an integer (for instance, does $3^k-1$ have some special significance)? If so, what are they called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the Mersenne numbers are called in a special way is inherited from the time when mathematicians were looking for generic formulas giving prime numbers.

So, there are the Mersenne numbers, but also the [Fermat numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number).
Fermat thought that this formula would give only primes, until Euler proved that
$$
641\mid 4294967297
$$
No one believes that every Fermat number except the 4 first are *not* prime.

Back to the powers $-1$, one can easily prove that
$$
a-b\mid a^n - b^n
$$

so if $a^n - 1$ is prime with $n>1$, then $a-1 = 1$. Which is why Mersenne numbers have a name and not the numbers in the form $a^n-1$ for any other $a$.

---

NB: this lemma also allows a quick proof of $2^p - 1$ is prime $\implies p$ is prime.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!